# Let $a,b$ and $c$ be real numbers where $a > b$. Prove that if $ac \leq bc$, then $c \leq 0$.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I have come across a problem:

> Let $a,b$ and $c$ be real numbers where $a > b$. Prove that if $ac \leq bc$, then $c \leq 0$.

I tried using the Indirect proof

If $a > b$, and $c > 0$, then by the 4th axiom of Inequality, Multiplicativity, $ac > bc$.

However, $ac \leq bc$, therefore $c \leq 0$.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct. This is also called a proof by contradiction since you assume that what you want to prove is false and then you derive a contradiction with what you had assumed in the problem.

So, if $a > b$ and $c> 0$, then $ac > ab$, but this contradicts the fact that $ac \leq ab$ and so the assumption that $c>0$ must be wrong. Hence $c \leq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the correct way .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/650298)

Comment: @Qwerty Thanks for your time. The author said "I'm not sure if this is the correct way", which means he is doubting whether is work is correct. Therefore, "your work is correct" is an answer.

Comment: No. It should be a comment. Answer only if you can show your work. Other wise anyone can post an answer "You are right" even if they have not done anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct.

Here's an alternative proof.

$bc \geq ac \Longleftrightarrow c(b-a) \geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow -c(a-b) \geq 0$

Since $a > b \Longleftrightarrow (a-b) >0$, so $c \leq 0$.